# Django Multiple fields in search error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have six text box in search field and user can enter either of the values. I capture those values in view by:

```
if request.GET:
     result_list = []
     client_build = request.GET.get('client_build','')
     app_build = request.GET.get('app_build','')
     ws_build = request.GET.get('ws_build','')
     asset = request.GET.get('asset','')
     feature = request.GET.get('feature','')
     test_type = request.GET.get('test_type','')
result_lists = result.objects.filter(asset=asset,feature=feature,      test_type=test_type)
     job_list = job.objects.filter(client_build=client_build ,app_build =   app_build,ws_build = ws_build)
```

When I try to filter them it gives "invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''" error! How can I get only those values which are entered by user and query in filter accordingly.

I referred to this post [Django - multiple field search issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626944/django-multiple-field-search-issues) but i have six text box doing multiple if and else is not what I am looking for.

Comment: is there some field that you are trying to query which is IntegerField but you are querying it with a string??

Comment: No! Only client_build is Integer other fields are CharField and I am entering them correctly. My query string in url : asset=ws&feature=&test_type=&client_build=&app_build=&ws_build= gives an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vikalp.sahni is correct. You enter an integer but you didn't know that the input convert your answer into string. To fix that, as you said that the client_build is the only integer, it must be:

```
client_build = int(request.GET.get('client_build',''))
```

Overall I think your query is correct. Just remember to put **int** if it is integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!    client_build = (request.GET.get('client_build',''))
                 cb = int('0'+client_build) worked for me!

Comment: But I have one more problem here. The filter does an AND over the query so If i dont enter one filed it does not give me any result.is there some way I can get the fields which are entered by user only and filter with those values?